# R: elements missing when saving to PDF

Tags: r, pdf-generation

R version 3.2.2 | R - Studio Version 0.99.484 | Windows 7

I am trying to plot and save to PDFs. When plotting to the plots-window in R-studio my plot appears nicely and I can manually save it from there. The saved PDF then looks as expected.

However, when trying to save the plot in my code, the legend and some text-elements are missing.

```
pdf(file=paste(filetitle, ".pdf",sep=""),paper="A4")
plotting_function(various parameters)

for (n in 1:number){
  x=sin(rad((-n+1)*deg))
  y=cos(rad((-n+1)*deg))
  km1_val=as.numeric(maxmin[4,n])
  km2_val=as.numeric(maxmin[3,n])
  if (km2_val>km1_val){
    km1_displace=0.8
    km2_displace=1.15
    }
  else {
  km2_displace=0.8
  km1_displace=1.15
    }
 text(x*km1_displace*km1_val/10, y*km1_displace*km1_val/10,round(maxmin[4,n],1),font=2,cex = .8,col=line_col_1)
 text(x*km2_displace*km2_val/10, y*km2_displace*km2_val/10, round(maxmin[3,n],1),font=2,cex = .8,col=line_col_2)
  }

legend(.55,-1.3,bty = "n",legend=c(colnames(q_data)[2],colnames(q_data)7]),cex=0.8,pch=c(16,16),col=c(line_col_2,line_col_1),lty=c(1,1))
text(0,1.5,title,font=2,cex=1.5)
text(-0.7,-1.4,"My_text",font=1,cex=.8)
dev.off()
```

The result of the plotting-function and the text-elements in the loop are included in the saved PDF, but the legend and the two text-elements below it are not included.

I have tried to use print() without success.

Any obvious mistakes?

Comment: Have you tried `grDevices::cairo_pdf`?

Comment: I did try using cairo_pdf(), when the pdf also missed the elements.

Comment: There is a superfluous `}` in your code. You should get an error and execution of code stops before your call to `legend`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Roland, I removed it. Unfortunately, the problem still persists. It has happened before that I've had to change code due to lazy evaluation, but that is hardly the case here? I do get the plot correctly drawn in R-Studio.

Comment: Present a reproducible example and you can get further help. Otherwise, good luck.

Comment: Is it possible that the legend and text are actually out of the visible area in the pdf? Does it work when you replace the `.55,-1.3,` in `legend()` by `"top",` ?

Comment: I had the same issue but it was only when viewing with Adobe Acrobat. Opening the pdf in Chrome worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

As Prolix suggested, trying to plot outside the plotting-area was the culprit. R-studio apparently adjusts for this when it shows the plot, whereas the error appears in the PDFs.